# No PrivateKey found for alias:'0‚' error in Jmeter for REST API

Tags: jmeter, ssl-certificate

We are implementing REST API in Jmeter. API has SSL certificate, Client id, Secret Key along with a Basic Authorization mechanism.

We are facing "javax.net.ssl.SSLException" & "No PrivateKey found for alias:'0‚'" errors.

We did the below settings in JMeter-

1. Added Client Certificate and password in the system.properties file
2. Added Client Id & Secret Key in User Parameters
3. Basic Authorization Credentials in HTTP Authorization Manager.

We are getting below response in JMeter logs-

2022-03-29 17:06:03,625 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
2022-03-29 17:06:03,625 WARN o.a.j.u.SSLManager: No password provided, and no GUI present so cannot prompt
2022-03-29 17:06:03,625 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Total of 1 aliases loaded OK from keystore D:/Projects /APITesting.pfx

and facing "javax.net.ssl.SSLException" & "No PrivateKey found for alias:'0‚'" errors.

Pls help us if we are missing anything in this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No password provided, and no GUI present so cannot prompt

It means that you didn't supply the password to the keystore where your certificates live via `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` JMeter System Property

Please double check your *system.properties* file and ensure that the password for the keystore is correct.

More information:

- [Keystore Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration)
- [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)

Comment: Hi, We have already added the password with the property- javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=Passw0rd                                                                                Let us know if we are still missing anything.

Comment: How many certificates do you have in the keystore? If more than one - make sure to provide relevant alias which exists in the keystore using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) like it's described in [How to Use Multiple Certificates When Load Testing Secure Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites) article. If only one - then remove Keystore Configuration from your Test Plan completely.

Comment: Working Now with this. Thank you for quick support.